# Why is 'at' used instead of 'in' or 'of in "safety is an absolute priority at Samsung"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

The following is the statement Samsung has issued:

> However, because our customers’ safety is an absolute priority **at** Samsung, we have stopped sales of the Galaxy Note7. ([Source](//news.samsung.com/global/statement-on-galaxy-note7))

I am wondering why "at" is used in this case instead of **"in"** or **"of"**. My basic idea about the preposition "at" is that it is more used when meaning physical places. For example, "I bought this at a store." So, if I wrote this, I would say "a priority of Samsung" or "a priority in Samsung." Are those prepositions interchangeable in this case? Or any differences between those?

Comment: Native English speakers commonly say, for instance, _"I am employed at Amazon."_ Dictionary.com (in fact, any English dictionary on Earth) has _(used to indicate presence or location)._ We assume that Samsung has a physical presence. It means _"a priority at Samsung's offices and by inference as part of our corporate ethos."_ This is not a remarkable usage.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thank you for the comment! Would you consider any differences between those three prepositions in this case? Can I interchange "at" with "in" or "of"?

Comment: Neither **of** nor **in** is appropriate or correct in this usage. **Of** would require the Saxon genitive to be applied to _Samsung,_ and "priority in Samsung" is meaningless. **At** is the preposition we use to express this kind of relationship in English. A writer could use _a priority **for** Samsung,_ though, with the same meaning.

Answer (score -2):

> However, because our customers’ safety is an absolute priority at
>   Samsung, we have stopped sales of the Galaxy Note7.

**'[at](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at)'** here is a combination of two meanings:

- **'at'** used as a function word to indicate the goal of an indicated or implied action or motion. Used to indicate something that is being tried or attempted.

> So *"customers’ safety"* is the goal the *"Samsung company"* is indicating
>   to or attempting to reach.

- **'at'** used to indicate the place where someone or something is. Used to indicate a particular place or time.

> So *"Samsung"* is the place where *"customers’ safety"* is an absolute priority.

**Conclusion:** Because *"customers’ safety"* is an absolute priority that was violated at the company "Samsung", they have stopped sales of the Galaxy Note7.

Comment: Please explain the down-votes!

Comment: You haven't explained why 'in' or 'of' couldn't be used, and I think folks object to the "implied action or motion". "Here at Samsung, we make customers' safety a priority." would be a more likely interpretation.